# Change value in arrays in array

Tags: unity, c#

The title might be confusing and I don't think this short explanation is 100% accurate, but I will try my best to show the problem.
So I have this hierarchy:

[image]

And I want to change "measureOfTime" value in all subWave in wave[i], because I had no clue how to do this in a short way (at least I bet there is a shorter way) and I made this:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Set this value here to set time to 1 wave")]
    public float timeUntilWave;
    [Header("Measure Time basically = 0")]
    public Wave[] waves;
    public float waveTime;
    public bool roundStarted;
    public int wave;

    private void Start()
    {
        wave = -1;
        roundStarted = false;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (timeUntilWave >= 0)
        {
            timeUntilWave = timeUntilWave - 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }else if (timeUntilWave < 0)
        {
            roundStarted = true;
            wave++;
        }
        if (roundStarted == true)
        {
            waveTime = waveTime + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
            int subwaveLenght = waves[wave].subWave.Length;
            int count = 0;
            while (count <= subwaveLenght)
            {
                waves[wave].subWave[count].measureOfTime = waves[wave].subWave[count].measureOfTime + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
                count++;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

And in lines 33 and 37 I see an error: "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

And here are 2 questions:
Why those errors appear here?

Is there an easier way to raise the value in arrays in an array?

I hope it's not too confusing, and thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a basic programming question that does not require game-specific expertise. When you get an error message you don't understand, you should always search for that error message text first. Chances are, you'll find lots of existing coverage about it on our general programming sister site, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IndexOutOfRangeException` happens whenever you try to access an array element with an index which is outside of the array.

Keep in mind that array indices start at 0, so the valid array indices are always one less than the length of the array. For example, when `subWave.Length` is `3`, then the available  array indices are `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`. That means a loop `while (count <= subWave.Length)` will try to access `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` and then the illegal index `[3]`.

You could fix that problem by changing that line to `while (count < subwaveLenght)`. But there is a more readable and less error-prone way to do something with all entries of an array. [A foreach loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in):

```
foreach(var subWave in waves[wave].subWave) {
     subWave.measureOfTime = subWave.measureOfTime + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Note that this will only work when subWave is a `class` and not a `struct`. When it is a struct, then the local variable `subWave` will be an independent copy of the array entry, and any changes you make to that copy will not automatically be written back to the original array.

---

Oh, and you are also not testing if `int wave` is out of range either. So that's the other source of `IndexOutOfRangeException`s which will occur as soon as you run out of waves. So:

```
    if (roundStarted == true && wave < waves.Length)
    {
         waveTime = waveTime + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
         foreach(var subWave in waves[wave].subWave) {
              subWave.measureOfTime = subWave.measureOfTime + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
         }    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, will be useful for sure.